# how to set within a property other "private" attributes

Tags: python, properties

Suppose the following code is given, Python 2.7

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self.__x = x
        self._y = self.x**2
```

We have an attribute `x` which once it is set / updated should also automatically set/update the attribute `_y`. `_y` is only used for internal calculation in other function. So far the motivation. Now if I do the following

```
>>> mytest = temp.A(2)
>>> mytest._y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute '_y'
>>>
```

is it not possible to set multiple attributes within via a property?

Comment: In Python 2, you should be using new-style classes, so your class should be declared `class A(object):`. Then your code works fine.

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301369/1453822

Comment: @khelwood looks like that fixes it. thx